# Using Directory API in Google-Apps-Script, how to get groups inside a group

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a script that gets all goups in my domain and lists all users in these groups.

I rewrote this script because `GroupsManager` is deprecated so my old script will stop working soon.

All is working well (although this API is quite slow...) but the issue I have is that some groups have not only users but include also other groups... some of them have only subgroups (and no users (way of speaking !)

I can't find any way to catch that situation, the [list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/#Groups) method return users, it ignores completely groups inside.

*So my question is :*

Is there a way to get the groups **inside a group** ?  Am I missing something obvious ?

Below and for info is the code I use to list all members in groups in a spreadsheet, 1 sheet / group so that I can manipulate these data faster and easier later on. I used background color flags as a track keeper to handle a (relatively) small batch operation and a timer trigger that make it work until it's done. (yes, we have a lot of groups in our domain ;-)

```
function listGroupMembers() {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1k-o4IVKEhW2zkk_________f2rH4UUt3OAC8I0ZoM');// set your SS ID (runs with timer trigger > needs to open by ID
  var pageToken, page;
  var count=0;
  var groupList = [];
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
      domain: 'xxxxx.be',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var gr = page.groups;
    if (gr) {
      for (var i = 0; i < gr.length; i++) {
        var group = gr[i];
        count++;
        //Logger.log(group);
        groupList.push([group.email,count])
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No group found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } 
  while (pageToken);
  try{
    var GroupAddress = ss.getSheetByName('GroupAddress');// if GroupAddress Sheet already exist, open it
    Logger.log('Use existing sheet "'+GroupAddress.getName()+'"');
  }catch(err){
    Logger.log('create sheet "GroupAddress"');
    ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
    var GroupAddress = ss.insertSheet('GroupAddress',0); //else create it as first sheet 
  }
  GroupAddress.getDataRange().clearContent();
  ss.getSheetByName('GroupAddress').getRange(1,1,groupList.length,groupList[0].length).setValues(groupList);

  var groupNames = ss.getSheetByName("GroupAddress").getDataRange().getValues();
  var groupDone = ss.getSheetByName("GroupAddress").getDataRange().getBackgrounds();
  var progress;
  for(var n in groupNames){
    if(groupDone[n][0] != 'white' || (new Date().getTime()-start)/60 > 5000){ // limit to 5 seconds + 1 group
      continue;
    }
    try{
      var outputSheet = ss.insertSheet(groupNames[n][0],Number(n)+1)
      }catch(err){
        var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName(groupNames[n][0]);
      }
    var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupNames[n][0]);
    //Logger.log('groupNames[n][0] = '+groupNames[n][0]);
    try{
      var users = group.getUsers();
      var output = [];
      for (var i in users){ 
        var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(users[i].getEmail());
        output.push([Number(i)+1,user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail,user.aliases!=null?user.aliases:'',new Date(user.creationTime),user.isAdmin,new Date(user.lastLoginTime)]);
      }
      ss.getSheetByName("GroupAddress").getRange(Number(n)+1,1).setBackground('#fff2cc');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      if(output.length>0){
        output.push(['durée :',parseInt((new Date().getTime()-start)/60),'millisecondes','','','','']);
        outputSheet.getRange(1,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
      }
    }catch(err){
      continue}
  }
  groupDone = ss.getSheetByName("GroupAddress").getDataRange().getBackgrounds();
  for(progress = groupDone.length-1;progress>=0;progress--){
    if(groupDone[progress][0]!='white'){break};
  }
  Logger.log(n+'='+progress+'?');
  if(n==progress){
    MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),'All jobs done in GroupList','All tasks completed on '+new Date().toLocaleString());
    var trig = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var t in trig){
      try{
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trig[t]);
      }catch(e){}
    }
  }else{
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('listGroupMembers').timeBased().after(3000).create();// wait 3 secs and continue
  }
}
```

---

### EDIT

Thanks to Göran's answer I have a version that gets all members of all groups including subgroups.

I changed (very) slightly his code to fit my requirements and I also needed to limit the number of cells in each sheet to what I needed because the total (1000*26 cells/sheet) was exceeding the 200000 cells limit (I have more than 100 sheets).

Full code below for anybody who would be interested (including menu and a few utilities):

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Utilitaires INSAS")
  .addItem("reset colors", "resetColors")
  .addItem("create groupUser lists", "listGroupMembers")
  .addItem("delete all sheets", "delsheets");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function listGroupMembers() {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1k-o4IVKEhW2zkkEu0gAvb92rQf2rH4UUt3OAC8I0ZoM');// set your SS ID (runs with timer trigger > needs to open by ID
  var pageToken, page;
  var count=0;
  var groupList = [];
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
      domain: 'insas.be',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var gr = page.groups;
    if (gr) {
      for (var i = 0; i < gr.length; i++) {
        var group = gr[i];
        count++;
        //Logger.log(group);
        groupList.push([group.email,count])
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No group found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } 
  while (pageToken);
  try{
    var GroupAddress = ss.getSheetByName('GroupAddress');// if GroupAddress Sheet already exist, open it
    Logger.log('Use existing sheet "'+GroupAddress.getName()+'"');
  }catch(err){
    Logger.log('create sheet "GroupAddress"');
    ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
    var GroupAddress = ss.insertSheet('GroupAddress',0); //else create it as first sheet 
  }
  GroupAddress.getDataRange().clearContent();
  ss.getSheetByName('GroupAddress').getRange(1,1,groupList.length,groupList[0].length).setValues(groupList);

  var groupNames = ss.getSheetByName("GroupAddress").getDataRange().getValues();
  var groupDone = ss.getSheetByName("GroupAddress").getDataRange().getBackgrounds();
  var progress;
  for(var n in groupNames){
    if(groupDone[n][0] != 'white' || (new Date().getTime()-start)/60 > 5000){ // limit to 5 seconds + 1 group
      continue;
    }
    Logger.log('groupNames[n][0] = '+groupNames[n][0]);
    try{
      var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName(groupNames[n][0]);
      Logger.log('sheet '+outputSheet.getName()+' created');
      }catch(err){
        var outputSheet = ss.insertSheet(groupNames[n][0],ss.getSheets().length+1);
      }
    try{
      var users = getUsersInGroup(groupNames[n][0]);
      var output = [];
      for (var i in users){ 
        var user = users[i];
//        Logger.log(user);
        output.push([Number(i)+1,user.email,user.role,user.groupName]);
      }
      ss.getSheetByName("GroupAddress").getRange(Number(n)+1,1).setBackground('#fff2cc');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      if(output.length>0){
        output.push(['Ex.T = '+parseInt((new Date().getTime()-start)/60)+' mS','','','']);
        outputSheet.getRange(1,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
        outputSheet.deleteRows(output.length+2, outputSheet.getMaxRows()-output.length-4);
        outputSheet.deleteColumns(6, outputSheet.getMaxColumns()-6);
      }
    }catch(err){
      continue}
  }
  groupDone = ss.getSheetByName("GroupAddress").getDataRange().getBackgrounds();
  for(progress = groupDone.length-1;progress>=0;progress--){
    if(groupDone[progress][0]!='white'){break};
  }
  Logger.log(n+'='+progress+'?');
  if(n==progress){
    MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),'All jobs done in GroupList','All tasks completed on '+new Date().toLocaleString());
    var trig = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var t in trig){
      try{
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trig[t]);
      }catch(e){}
    }
  }else{
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('listGroupMembers').timeBased().after(10000).create();// wait 3 secs and continue
  }
}

function resetColors(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().setBackground(null);
}

function getUsersInGroup(rootGroup) {
  var groupTreeUsers = [];
  var groups = [];
  groups.push(rootGroup);

  while (groups.length > 0) {
    var currentGroup = groups.pop();
    var groupName = AdminDirectory.Groups.get(currentGroup).name;
    var groupMembers = getAllMembers_(currentGroup);

    for (var i in groupMembers) {
      if (groupMembers[i].type == 'USER') {
        var groupMember = groupMembers[i];
        groupMember['groupName'] = currentGroup;
        groupTreeUsers.push(groupMember)
      }
      else if (groupMembers[i].type == 'GROUP') {
        groups.push(groupMembers[i].email)
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log('There are %s user members in %s (including sub groups)', groupTreeUsers.length, rootGroup);
  return groupTreeUsers;
}

function getAllMembers_(group) {
  var memberPageToken, memberPage;
  var members = [];
  do {
    memberPage = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group, {
      maxResults: 200,
      pageToken: memberPageToken
    });
    var pageMembers = memberPage.members;
    if (pageMembers) {
      for (var j =0; j < pageMembers.length; j++) {
        members.push(pageMembers[j]);
      }
    }
    memberPageToken = memberPage.nextPageToken;
  } while (memberPageToken);
  return members;
}

function delsheets(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numSheets = ss.getNumSheets();// check how many sheets in the spreadsheet
  for (var pa=numSheets-1;pa>0;pa--){ 
    if(ss.getSheets()[pa].getSheetName()!='GroupAddress'){
      ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheets()[pa]); // delete sheets begining with the last one
      Utilities.sleep(100);
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AdminDirectory MembersCollection might be what you are looking for.

Example snippet:

```
var members = AdminDirectory.Members.list('testgroup@example.com').members;
for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
  var member = members[i];
  switch (member.type) {
    case 'USER':
      Logger.log('%s is a user', member.email);
      break;
    case 'GROUP':
      Logger.log('%s is a group', member.email);
      break;
    default:
      Logger.log('This will never happen');
  }
```

Some of my customers have groups containing groups contaning groups... forming a group tree with arbitrary depth. I use this code to get all user members in such a group tree:

```
function walkTreeStack() {
  var rootGroup = 'testgroup@example.com';
  var groupTreeUsers = [];
  var groups = [];
  groups.push(rootGroup);

  while (groups.length > 0) {
    var currentGroup = groups.pop();
    var groupName = AdminDirectory.Groups.get(currentGroup).name;
    var groupMembers = getAllMembers_(currentGroup);

    for (var i in groupMembers) {
      if (groupMembers[i].type == 'USER') {
        groupTreeUsers.push([groupName, groupMembers[i].email])
      }
      else if (groupMembers[i].type == 'GROUP') {
        groups.push(groupMembers[i].email)
      }
    }
  }

  Logger.log('There are %s user members in %s (including sub groups)', groupTreeUsers.length, groupName);
}

function getAllMembers_(group) {
  var memberPageToken, memberPage;
  var members = [];
  do {
    memberPage = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group, {
      maxResults: 200,
      pageToken: memberPageToken
    });
    var pageMembers = memberPage.members;
    if (pageMembers) {
      for (var j =0; j < pageMembers.length; j++) {
        members.push(pageMembers[j]);
      }
    }
    memberPageToken = memberPage.nextPageToken;
  } while (memberPageToken);
  return members;
}
```

It's slightly faster if it's done recursively but I suspect the script might crash due to memory constraints if there are a large number of sub groups and user members:

```
function getGroupTreeMembers() {
  var rootGroup = 'testgroup@example.com';
  var groupTreeUsers = [];

  walkTreeRecursive_(rootGroup, groupTreeUsers);

  var groupName = AdminDirectory.Groups.get(rootGroup).name;  
  Logger.log('There are %s user members in %s (including sub groups)', groupTreeUsers.length, groupName);
}

function walkTreeRecursive_(rootGroup, groupTreeUsers) {
  var groupName = AdminDirectory.Groups.get(rootGroup).name;
  var groupMembers = getAllMembers_(rootGroup);
  var groups = [];
  for (var i in groupMembers) {
    if (groupMembers[i].type == 'USER') {
      groupTreeUsers.push([groupName, groupMembers[i].email])
    }
    else if (groupMembers[i].type == 'GROUP') {
      groups.push(groupMembers[i].email)
    }
  }
  for (var i in groups) {
    walkTreeRecursive_(groups[i], groupTreeUsers);
  }
}
```

For more information please visit:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members#resource

Comment: Great ;-) this does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much !

Comment: I just had to edit the final Log to show the correct log :   `Logger.log('There are %s user members in %s (including sub groups)', groupTreeUsers.length, rootGroup);`
 but that's really a "cosmetic" change XD

Comment: btw, your code runs a little bit faster than mine... about 1.5 times faster, not that it's so important but it's always worth gaining a few seconds isn't it ? thanks again, I'll edit my code with the (small) change needed to integrate yours.

Comment: I just can't get all the informations I had with my call to AdminDirectory.Users.list but I'll find a way to combine both if I need to.

Comment: @Serge Please note that users that are member in more one than group will appear in multiple elements in the resuting array (groupTreeUsers)

Comment: not an issue, I can handle that by removing duplicates if needed. I changed your code slightly to add the group name in the returned value to show it in another column in the group sheet. I'm fine tuning the whole thing before updating my post... had to limit the number of cells because I was exceeding the limit ;-)

Comment: Answer updated :-) As you will see, I didn't change a lot of things : just added a property to users so that I can easily see which group a user belongs to when I have subgroups. Maybe  I'll try to expand the script to get fullName but after all I'm not sure I need that... email is enough for now ! thanks for your help.