# How to sync a Google Groups membership with a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-admin-sdk, google-groups

G'day,

I have several Google Groups under a Google Apps account that my nonprofit uses. Some of these groups are quite large and managing their membership with the web UI is pretty awful.

I'm hoping someone can help me come up with a script that can synchronize a list that I maintain on a Google Docs Spreadsheet with a Group so that when I remove someone from the sheet, they get removed from the group -- and when someone gets added to the sheet, they get added to the group.

I was taking a look at the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members) but I'm not savvy enough to figure out how to build a script for what I need. Side note, I did play around with a [different script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455649/using-directory-api-in-google-apps-script-how-to-get-groups-inside-a-group) someone posted here that uses similar API methods, and I got that particular script to work -- so in other words, my account is now properly set up for API access.

Perhaps the easiest way to do this programmatically would be to delete the group's membership entirely, then add each member again, each time the script runs?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Maybe have one column where you put an "X" in the cell if you want a member deleted, then run a script that finds all the rows with the "X", deletes the member, then deletes the row.  That's for deletion.  Then have a sheet for new member additions, add the new member in just that special sheet, then run a script that adds all the members, then appends the person to the regular list.  That would be a simple interface.  You could create special forms, but that would be more work.  Would something like that work for you?

Comment: Yes that would be perfect and probably a better idea than completely erasing the group membership each time it runs. Would you be able to help me write something like that, or point me in the direction of where I should start? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several functions that you can use to accomplish what you would like.

First here is the removal process.  As commented by Sandy, create a column that you will use to mark members for removal. You should be able use what ever you like here as long as the ones not being deleted are blank. You will need to change the variable "marked" to reflect that columns number, you will also need to do the same for the "email" variable.  That being the column that holds the users emails.

Make a copy of your sheet first and make sure that when the rows are deleted that they are the correct ones!

```
/**
 *Removes members from group that are marked for removal in a specific column
 */
function removeMarkedMembers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();

  //Adjust these following variables to match your sheet
  var groupEmail = 'group@email.com';//change to your group email address
  var marked = 7;//number of column used to mark for removal ex. Column A = 1
  var email = 4; //number of column that holds member email address.

  //must adjust columns numbers to zero based array integers
  marked = marked-1;
  email = email-1;

  var rows = [];

  for (var d in data) {
    var rowData = data[d];
    if(rowData[marked] != "" || rowData != null) {
      removeGroupMember(groupEmail, rowData[email]);
      rows.push(new Number(d)+1)
    }
  }

  for (var r in rows) {
    sheet.deleteRow(rows[r])
  }
}


function removeGroupMember(groupEmail, userEmail) {
  userEmail = userEmail.trim();
  AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, userEmail);
}
```

Lastly here are some other functions for managing groups, use them as needed.  Probably best to create a menu that you can just call these from inside the spreadsheet.

```
/**
 *Adds all email addresses in column to group.
 */
function addAllToGroup() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var column = 7;
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow(), 1)
  var emails = range.getValues();

  for (var e in emails) {
    var email = emails[e]
    if(validateEmail(email)) {
      addGroupMember(email, 'your@groupemailaddress.com');////Must replace with group email address you want them added too.
    }
  }  
}


function addGroupMember(userEmail, groupEmail) {
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };
  AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
}

function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
} 

/**
 *Removes all members from a defined group
 */
function removeAllMembers() {
  var groupEmail = 'group@email.com';
  var members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupEmail).members;

  for (var m in members) {
    var member = members[m];
    var email = member.email;
    removeGroupMember(groupEmail, email);
  }
}
```

This should help you get a nice finished product.

**Edited Code to handle reported errors in the comments.**
Also updated the marked column must use an "x" for marker to be removed.
Lastly to properly handle the deletion of the row, you need to clear it and then sort the entire sheet or your will get wrong rows removed. Remember to adjust to your parameters.

```
/**
 *Removes members from group that are marked for removal in a specific column
 */
function removeMarkedMembers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = range.getValues();

  Logger.log(data)

  //Adjust these following variables to match your sheet
  var groupEmail = 'test-group@email.com';//change to your group email address
  var marked = 2;//number of column used to mark for removal ex. Column A = 1
  var email = 1; //number of column that holds member email address.

  //must adjust columns numbers to zero based array integers.
  marked = marked-1;
  email = email-1;

  Logger.log(marked+' : '+email)

  var rows = [];

  for (var d in data) {
    var rowData = data[d];
    if(validateEmail(rowData[email]) && rowData[marked] == "x") {
      Logger.log('marked')
      removeGroupMember(groupEmail, rowData[email]);
      rows.push(new Number(d)+2)
    }
  }

  for (var r in rows) {
    var row = rows[r];
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).clear();
  }
 range.sort(1);
}


function removeGroupMember(groupEmail, userEmail) {
  Logger.log(userEmail)
  userEmail = userEmail.trim();
  AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, userEmail);
}

/**
 *Adds all email addresses in column to group.
 */
function addAllToGroup() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var column = 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow(), 1)
  var emails = range.getValues();

  for (var e in emails) {
    var email = emails[e]
    if(validateEmail(email)) {
      addGroupMember(email, 'test-group@email.com');////Must replace with group email address you want them added too.
    }
  }  
}


function addGroupMember(userEmail, groupEmail) {
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };
  var members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupEmail).members
  for (var m in members) {
    if(members[m].email == userEmail) {
      return 'Member already exist';
    }
  }
  AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
}

function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
} 

/**
 *Removes all members from a defined group
 */
function removeAllMembers() {
  var groupEmail = 'test-group@email.com';
  var members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupEmail).members;

  for (var m in members) {
    var member = members[m];
    var email = member.email;
    removeGroupMember(groupEmail, email);
  }
}
```

Comment: Lenny - thank you very much, I really appreciate it. I gave it a spin and it's very close, but there's a couple things I'm hoping you can help fix. 1) Adding multiple members at one time does work, but only if the members are new to the list. If members are already on the list, I get the error "Member already exists." Can it be updated so that if a member already exists it just skips over that member and moves on? Also, 2) "removeMarkedMembers" doesn't work; I get the error "Missing required field: memberKey." I haven't been able to remove a member at all yet -- any advice? Thanks again!

Comment: Added edited code, thanks for heads up. Would appreciate a check on the answer if it all works for you.

Comment: Thank you! Deletions work _perfectly_ now - however, comically, adding does not work anymore. I don't get error messages anymore; instead, it always says "Finished script" even though it never adds any emails to the group. FYI, I've tried adding a single email (which worked before) as well as multiple emails at once. Also, I've tried emptying out the group to start clean -- no dice. Do you know what might be causing that? Thanks again... it's so close! You're the man Lenny.

Comment: It seems to be working correctly for me.  Did you update the referenced column for the email addresses. I'm using column A in the example, you can change that column number to which ever you need?

Comment: You are correct. I didn't notice the `var column` at first in `addAllToGroup` -- I changed that to the correct col and it works perfectly! I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: No worries, had most of it built already.   Appreciate the vote up.