# Trying to remove Google Groups members gives Not Authorized exception

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I have a google apps script attached to a Google Sheets document.  I have the following code.

```
function addGroupMember() {
  var userEmail = 'aaa@example.com';
  var groupEmail = 'list@mysite.org';
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
}

function removeGroupMember() {
  var userEmail = 'aaa@example.com';
  var groupEmail = 'list@mysite.org';
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.remove(member, groupEmail);
}
```

The first function works fine to add group members.  The second function to delete group members throws the exception "Not Authorized to access this resource/api".  I am executing this as an administrator user and I can edit all Google Groups with no problem through the admin UI.  What else do I need to get authorized to execute this script?

As far as I can tell, I followed the steps to create authorization on the notes section here - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory.

My goal is to parse emails from my spreadsheet and use the functions to add/remove members from my Google Groups.

Comment: Maybe this is because the 'remove' method of Members Resource takes 'groupKey' and 'memberKey' as parameters. The method signature is: AdminDirectory.Members.remove(String groupKey, String memberKey). Hope that helps!

Comment: So it should be remove(groupEmail, userEmail).

Comment: The groupKey is the group's unique id, and memberKey is the deleted user or group member's primary email address or the user's unique id. For your reference:  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#delete_member

Comment: Thanks, KRR.  The parameters weren't passed correctly!

Comment: More group with spreadsheet reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727200/how-to-sync-a-google-groups-membership-with-a-google-spreadsheet/27757928#27757928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KRR provided the correct answer in his comment.  The parameters were not passed correctly.  Pasting his comment here.

> Maybe this is because the 'remove' method of Members Resource takes 'groupKey' and 'memberKey' as parameters. The method signature is: AdminDirectory.Members.remove(String groupKey, String memberKey). Hope that helps!